# Design map pop up box in css

Tags: html, css

Now my css:

```
#setlocation {
    position:absolute;
    width:420px;
    height:125px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 75px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-color: #000;
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? What is the problem? Be more specific.

Comment: This isn't rent a coder, post what you have tried and we will try to steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

It would help you. It's less HTML (so more much clear) and less CSS. tables is not good for that things (it's only an example): [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t9df99ta/3/)

```
.setlocation-ok * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.setlocation-ok {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #aeaeae;
    background: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position:relative;
}
.setlocation-ok:before {
    content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -14px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.setlocation-ok .close {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d1d1d1;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
.setlocation-ok .close:hover {
    background: #c1c1c1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.setlocation-ok label {
  display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #2782a3;
}
.setlocation-ok input[type=text] {
display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.setlocation-ok input[type=submit] {
    border: none;
  background: #2782a3;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div style="padding: 50px; background: #ccc;">
  <div class="setlocation-ok">
    <form action="/maps/jmap160_netv1.asp?action=4" method="post" name="30">
      <label>Enter your address</label>
      <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Example: 123 Lead st, Henderson, NV" />
      <input type="submit" value="Set location" />
    </form>
    <span class="close">x</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, here you have [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t9df99ta/3/) with close button

Comment: So the OP provides not even half a question but you still feel the need to answer it? This is why people continuously post poor / low quality questions because community members keep answering them.